# Polygon not drawing correctly

Tags: polygon, java, geotools

I have a series of points I would like to connect into a polygon but it isn't drawing correctly, You'll see the problem.

```
Coordinate[] xyarray = xycoords.toCoordinateArray();                                                                    

LinearRing shell = geomFactory.createLinearRing(xyarray);                                                               
Polygon poly = geomFactory.createPolygon(shell, new LinearRing[0]);                                                     

Geometry perimeterline = geomFactory.createPolygon(xyarray);                                                            
GeometryCollector xypoints = new GeometryCollector();                                                                   
xypoints.add(poly);                                                                                                     
GeometryCollection xygeoms = xypoints.collect();                                                                        

File xyshp = new File("perimeterline.shp");                                                                             
File xyshx = new File("perimeterline.shx");                                                                             
FileOutputStream xysshp = new FileOutputStream(xyshp);                                                                  
FileOutputStream xysshx = new FileOutputStream(xyshx);                                                                  
ShapefileWriter xywriter = new ShapefileWriter(xysshp.getChannel(), xysshx.getChannel());                               
xywriter.write(xygeoms, ShapeType.POLYGON);
```

[image]

Comment: Without knowing what is in `xycoords` it's hard to tell what is up, but why do you collect the polygon? and why are you using the inner workings of shapefile writer rather than a ShapefileDatastore?

Comment: A polygon is defined by an ordered set of vertices that walk the perimeter of the figure. You don't have a polygon in the vertices, so the result is a mess. It seems as if you could point that vertex stream to a convex hull generator, and then you'd get a polygon.

Comment: Ok I'll try that, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the end I took the centroid of the bounding box and calculated the azimuth of every point to sort the coordinates and it then drew in order.